# In Webots is there a way to easily modify an existing robot (like the Mavic drone)

Tags: webots

I am wondering if there's an easy way of modifying an existing robot, such as the Mavic drone, and then test how this modification worked.

For example, I would like to change the shape or angle of the blades.

I have opened the Mavic demo, and I have converted the Drone "convert the root to base node" and I see more nodes, but I am not sure if this would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is not a bad approach to quickly test modifications on a PROTO. However, instead of `Convert Root to Base Node(s)`, you should have selected `Convert to Base Node(s)`. Once you have converted the PROTO to base nodes in the scene tree, you should be able to open the resulting base node and its children to modify them and immediately see how your changes affect the model in the 3D view.

However, the recommended way to modify an existing robot is to create a local copy of the PROTO of the robot and modify it in a text editor.

In order to proceed:

1. Open a world file, for example the Mavic demo. From the Webots `File` menu, `Open Sample World...`, then type `mavic` in the `Find:` search box and click on `mavic_2_pro.wbt`.
2. If it is running, stop the simulation and reset it <kbd>|<<</kbd> or reload it <kbd>⟲</kbd>.
3. In the scene tree (left hand side), right-click on the `Mavic2Pro "Mavic 2 PRO"` node located at the bottom of the list and select `Edit PROTO Source`.
4. Proceed with the two dialog boxes to download the PROTO file and relocate the project inside your own folders. The Webots text editor should now display a new tab entitled `Mavic2Pro.proto` with a copy of the original PROTO file.
5. Edit this copy of the `Mavic2Pro.proto` file to make your own changes, save the PROTO file and reload the simulation to see the result of your changes.
6. Repeat step 5 as much as you need.

For details on how to edit a PROTO file, see the [reference PROTO documentation](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/proto) and the [PROTO tutorial](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-7-your-first-proto).

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*

Comment: @OlivierMichael, is there any guide about how to modify proto files?

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer.